# What is this clump of hot and dim stars? (Gaia H-R diagram)

Tags: astrophysics, stars

On the recently released H-R diagram of data from Gaia DR2, there is a clump of hot but not very luminous stars around 30,000K and less than 10 solar luminosity.  I can't find this clump on any other H-R diagram.  What are these objects? My first thought is they may be neutron stars or another stellar remnant, but that doesn't seem likely.

[image: Gaia H-R diagram]

Comment: Just a guess: maybe they're young O stars that are obscured by a dense gas cloud (e.g. in a star-forming region)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that these are [subdwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdwarf) - well, really, [O-type subdwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdwarf_O_star)  and [B-type subdwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdwarf_B_star), which are distinct from the other subdwarf populations (which retain their hydrogen). They're largely composed of helium, with a thin shell of hydrogen at their surface. While the exact mechanism of their formation is unknown, [it's likely that they've lost mass to a companion](http://physics.highpoint.edu/~bbarlow/subdwarfs.html), donating much of their hydrogen envelopes and retaining helium and the carbon/oxygen/etc. in their cores. There are, however, other proposed formation mechanisms, including a late helium flash of sorts in a red giant or the merger of two white dwarfs, both with low amounts of hydrogen.

The HR diagram given in [Heber (2009)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009ARA%26A..47..211H) shows these populations, to the far left (Figure 1). They fall to the left of the main sequence, hotter than many white dwarfs and main sequence O- and B- type stars. While these subdwarfs are hot, they are much less luminous than these main sequence stars because of their size (perhaps 0.1-0.2 solar radii).